# Expo push notifications working on expo go but not working on apk ( production )

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm trying to implement [expo push notification](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/) ! I did everything as the docs say.
Created a firebase project and downloaded the `google-services.json` and uploaded the server key on the cloud messaging to expo servers using  `expo push:android:upload --api-key <your-token-here>` ! so basically I did everything mentioned on their docs! My notifications works perfectly fine when I test it on the Expo GO ! but after I built an apk using `eas build -p android --profile preview`
The notification doesn't pop up! the api that I send from says that the notification was sent but it doesn't show on the device!
I read that notifications work on expo go and not apk because of the credentials! did I miss a step or something?
When I go to the expo builds and go to the project credentials Two options pop up, One by the path of com.company.app and the other one : by Legacy ( classic build)!

`app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myapp",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.hyrix.myapp",
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "ee001501-c3b5-402f-8a1d-914144496965"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you setup FCM key on expo.dev for your app?

Comment: @Zaki Kendil, Could you share your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Android Studios's logcat after connect your android smartphone to your PC.

I've tried to debug the app in Android Studio's logcat and got the following error message:

> '[expo-notifications] Error encountered while updating the device push token with the server:', '{"errors":[{"code":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"\"appId\" must be a string.","isTransient":false}]}'

What I did to solve this issue was set "applicationId" manually in  the `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()` method. Ex:

```
Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({applicationId: "xxxxxx..."})
```

The `applicationId` can be found in app's firebase config as `appId`.
The method `getExpoPushTokenAsync()` can receive some parameters, maybe some of them are not being set correctly.

Comment: In order to create token for physical device `Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync({applicationId: "xxxxxx..."})` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set the `projectId` in the method `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync`

So check that this method is called like this

```
token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
  projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
});
```

Note: You can also set the projectId manually instead of getting it from expo-constants module